# Implementing External Source Code Block in Lua

Tags: python, lua

I'm looking to write a Lua script and have it also execute something from Python source code as well, as if it went like so:

```
#!/bin/lua

-- begin lua part
print "Hello"

-- begin python part

Somehow_Executes_Python {
print "Hello" #In python, of course
}

-- End Script
```

Getting the idea?
I'm not sure if it's even possible, but if I can somehow implement foreign source code in controlled blocks, that would be great. I've seen other things about calling them from a different file/ link/ source, but I'm looking to have it work directly from inside of the lua source code, not from a different file entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local python = function(code)
  local file = assert(io.popen('python', 'w'))
  file:write(code)
  file:close()
end

-- begin lua part
print "Hello from Lua"

--begin python part

python [=[
print "Hello from Python"
]=]

-- End Script
```

Line-by-line explanation (without code highlighting, it seems that it is broken for Lua on the SO):

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
-- The above is a more sure-fire way to run Lua on linux from a shebang

-- This function runs python code as follows
local python = function(code)
  -- It opens a write pipe to the python executable
  local file = assert(io.popen('python', 'w'))
  -- pipes the code there
  file:write(code)
  -- and closes the file
  file:close()
  -- This is an equivalent of running
  -- $ python <code.py
  -- in the shell.
end

-- Begin Lua part
-- I added "from Lua" to better see in the output what works or not.
print "Hello from Lua"

-- Begin Python part
-- We're calling our python code running function, 
-- passing Lua long string to it. This is equivalent of
-- python('print "Hello from Python"')
python [=[
print "Hello from Python"
]=]

-- End Script
```

I imagine you would like to have at least some interoperability between Lua and Python code. It is a bit more difficult to implement and the way you should do it highly depends on the details of the problem you're actually solving.

The cleanest way would probably to create a socket pair of one kind or another and to make Lua and Python code to talk over it.

Solutions where you may read a variable or call a function from one VM (say Lua) in another (say Python) and vice-versa usually lead to a mess for a multitude of reasons (I tried a lot of them and implemented several myself).

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the parts you added mean and do, so I can better understand them in future uses? Assuming of course, that it works, which I have yet to try.

Comment: Alright. So I ran a few things with the modifications in your post, and it indeed worked properly for simple python code. Though I still would appreciate a broader explanation for each individual aspect so I can better understand what it's doing. Additionally, I'm wondering if I can cross variables from the python snippet to the lua snippet. Say I put one = "purple" in the python part, could I then follow outside of that with a lua line printing that variable?

Comment: Explanation added. This is very basic Lua, the _Programming in Lua_ book should help you to get a more in-depth view of what's going on.

Comment: `Say I put one = "purple" in the python part, could I then follow outside of that with a lua line printing that variable?` No, you can not. See two last paragraphs in my update.

Comment: If you still have something unclear left, please do ask specific questions.

Comment: Apologies, I seem to have written that both as you were writing that response, and before having read it. The way I'm picking this up is by informing myself of individual things I wish to do, and researching them independently, as opposed to following an entire book cover to cover. Perhaps this is the wrong method, since I've yet to consider myself proficient in any language. That is, I know small bits and pieces of a lot of languages. None of which is probably extremely helpful in the long run, if I don't simply have one down and done to some level of use.

Comment: No problem. I believe I left you enough keywords to google up an explanation of each concept. I could screw up the terminology somewhere, so if you can't research a topic to your satisfaction, please ask.

Comment: BTW, I really advise you to get a copy of a recent edition of _Programming in Lua_ and read it. If there is one single book you have to read on the programming, it is the one. And it is rather short.

Comment: This is really all for now, and your help was well appreciable. My final question is probably where you would suggest I look, in terms of learning Lua properly/ fully. Where should I start, and what should I read? Assuming what I previously mentioned, what with my scattered but basic knowledge and all.

Comment: Like I say, read the PiL (just make sure to read an edition for the version of Lua you will be initially coding for, don't read the online 5.0 edition just because it is freely available). That's all.

Comment: I added a remark to the answer re. variable-level interop.

Comment: Seems to be we've persistently managed to respond in peculiar ways, such that I ask the question after the answer has been given! I will pick one of those up. Anything else you suggest either alongside or after reading it?

Comment: I can easily get my hands on a copy of the third edition, but the fourth just came out and I can't get it as easily, additionally it wouldn't have a digital version at this time, making it a bit less efficient to use in my book. (Pun intended). See any large downside to using the third, versus the fourth?

Comment: Not sure, haven't seen the fourth myself. But the third is already excellent.

Comment: Aye. Well the fourth claims to have a full reorganization given new scaling and implement the latest version, all of which sounds juicy! In any case, if you find the third to be sufficient, I can't really argue here.  What do I do with this book, read it in a linear fashion and test the listed code snippets?

Comment: It really depends on how do you prefer to learn. The chapters in 3rd are more or less independent, AFAIR, so you probably can process them out of order. Running at least some snippets yourself is, of course, a must.

Comment: In my practice the process is highly individual. But I never had patience to read chapters of any study book in order :) (And this is getting highly offtopic)

Answer (score -1):

There is a python-lua package called Lupa. Here's the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa). See if that helps.

Comment: Pardon, I'm not entirely certain of how that works. It looks to me like the absolute inverse of what I was asking, but then I am a bit tired and only skimmed it.